# How do you create a CString from a String in rust?

Tags: string, rust

How does one create a `std::ffi::CString` from a `String` in Rust?

Assume the `String` is already stored in a variable that can be moved if necessary, *NOT* a literal like it is in many of the examples for constructing a `CString`.

I have studied the docs for both `CString`:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html

and `String`:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html

and I still don't see the path. You must have to go through one of the many pointer types; `Into` and `From` aren't implemented for these types, so `.into()` doesn't work.

Comment: The creation examples in `CString` docs show `CString::new("Hello, world!")`. While `"Hello, world!"` is not a `String` but a `&str`, if you have a `String`, you can always get a `&str` from it using the `as_str()` method or in most cases a simple reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-From%3CString%3E) implements `Into<Vec<u8>>` already:

```rust
use std::ffi::CString;


fn main() {
    let ss = "Hello world".to_string();
    let s = CString::new(ss).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=14e653fbc26c5d2deb45c3fc8e636b20)